# Calculate variance of the integral of a stochastic process

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, variance

How do I calculate the variance of an integral of a stochastic process $X(t)$? I.e 
$$V\left[\int_0^1 X(t)dt\right]$$
?

Comment: Is $X(t)$ a stochastic process (i.e. a sequence of r.v. over time $t$)?

Comment: @the_candyman Yes.

Comment: Need some more information about $X(t)$; in general there isn't much we can say.